# Trying to integrate tinymce in a project however it doesnt work

Tags: angularjs, tinymce

I have an up and running project in Angularjs where we used CKEditor, now we want to use TinyMCE. I need to know how can I do this. I have also pasted my files. Please refer and answer my questions

I have run a standalone project in angularjs and it worked but when I am trying it with our up and running project, it doesnt make any changes to the textarea. Have pasted all the files. Textarea does not change. I think there is something wrong with the way I call the  class="text1"of textEditor.html

```
index.html

<script src="/js/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.5.6/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.5.6/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.9.5/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-tinymce/0.0.19/tinymce.js'></script>
<!-- AngularUI TinyMCE -->


route.js

state('tinymceEditor', {
url: '/tinymce_editor',
templateUrl: '/views/tinyEditor.html',
controller: 'tinyEditorController'
});

texteditor.html

<html>
<head>
<!--  -->

<!-- AngularUI TinyMCE -->
</head>
<body>
<form>
<textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" class="text1" id="mytextarea" ng-model="tinymceModel">Hello, World!</textarea>

</form>
</body>
</html>

tinyEditorController.js

(function () {
'use strict';

function tinyEditorController($scope,$state,$window,$http) {
tinyMCE.init({
selector: 'text1', 
})

$scope.tinymceOptions = {
plugins: 'link image code',
toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code '
};

$scope.model= "text";
}
angular
.module('qbAuthoringToolApp')
.controller('tinyEditorController', tinyEditorController);

tinyEditorController.$inject = ['$scope','$state','$window','$http'];

})();
```

I want this to work

Comment: Try with different version of tinymce

Comment: How do I read text from tinymce  to angularjs. Used $scope.variable = "Hello world"; when reading it from the textarea of tinymce it just gives the defined values i.e. Hello world and does not give any edited value from the text editor